# Docker service doesn't start on unprivileged lxc container on boot

Tags: docker, proxmox, lxc

I have proxmox with an Ubuntu lxc container where docker is installed and containers running. When I reboot my node, although the lxc container starts on boot, docker services start only when I login as root in the console. Is there a way

1. lxc automatically logs in (as root or another user on boot)
2. docker service start automatically irrespective of there been an automatic login or not
   Thank you in anticipation